# pnpm -- sync versions of dependencies

Tags: monorepo, pnpm

Let's say I have the following stricture for a Javascript monorepo

```
-- module a
   package.json
-- module b
   package.json
package.json
```

Module A and Module B both depend on lodash.

With pnpm, is there any way to ensure that they both use the same version of lodash? Like perhaps installing lodash in the root directory and saying "use whatever version is in the root of the workspace"?

P.S. I know that pnpm allows or workspaces, but to my understanding (which can be wrong), that's only used if the dependencies are already a module in the monorepo — not for 3rd-party dependencies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `overrides` field in your `package.json` to achieve this.

https://pnpm.io/package_json#pnpmoverrides

```js
{
  "pnpm": {
    "overrides": {
      "lodash": "4.17.20"
    }
  }
}
```

A similar feature exists in Yarn, called `resolutions`. Apparently there are some differences, though I'm not familiar with the specifics. [The feature was added here.](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/pull/2946)

##### Update - alternative approach

You can also try [`syncpack`](https://github.com/JamieMason/syncpack) if the `overrides` solution doesn't sit well with you. At my organization we're slowly moving towards `syncpack` for issues where the dependencies are only requested by our monorepo packages; the rationale for this is that too many overrides were accumulating over time.

But for ensuring the versions of dependencies of dependencies, `overrides` is still what you need.

e.g. if you install `react-dom` and it depends on `scheduler` and you need a specific version of `scheduler` for some reason, then the `overrides` approach is your only option - `syncpack` can't help there.

Comment: Thanks! Just for anyone coming here in 2022 the link should be: https://pnpm.io/package_json#pnpmoverrides